# Rendering a Sitecore field in MVC with an enclosing tag and class

Tags: mvc, renderfield

We effectively have an item with three fields.

1. Text to display in a heading.
2. Droplink with the type of heading to display the text in (`h1`, `h2`, ...).
3. Droplink with the heading style that points to the `class`(es) to add to the heading.

Based upon past experience I believed I would be able to do something like `@Html.Sitecore().Field(Templates.PageText.Fields.PageTextHeading.ToString(), Model.Item, new { @class = headingStyle, EnclosingTag = headingRank })`, but while the heading is properly displaying the class is not.

If I just do `<div>@headingStyle</div>` immediately before the above I do see the proper class name, suggesting that the values are coming across. I can also force a value to both the variable or in the anonymous object and the class still doesn't display.

Given that the heading can be variable, I don't really want to write a check to see what heading is selected just to manually add it.

Can I use Sitecore 8.2 Update-6 MVC functionality to add an enclosing tag, with a class, to the value of a text field?

Comment: Just for debugging purposes, have you tried putting a hardcoded value in there to see if it processes the hardcoded value? I'm wondering if the value is there but is somehow in a bad format (perhaps not enough quotation marks?)

Comment: did you try :
@Html.Sitecore().Field(Templates.PageText.Fields.PageTextHeading.ToString(), Model.Item, new { Before = "<h1class=\"example\">", After = "</h1>" })

Comment: Jay: "I can also force a value to both the variable or in the anonymous object and the class still doesn't display." Vlad: Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work for you:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field(Templates.PageText.Fields.PageTextHeading.ToString(), Model.Item, new { @class = headingStyle, EnclosingTag = headingRank })
```

is that Sitecore tries to add `@class` attribute to the tag rendered from the field value itself, not from the `EnclosingTag`. If your field was a `LinkField`, the output would be:

```
<h1><a class="headingStyle">LINK_TEXT</a></h1>
```

Sitecore cannot add a class attribute to the text which doesn't have any html tag.

That's why the only option is what **Vlad Iobagliu** wrote in his comment:

```
var before = string.format("<{0} class=\"{1}\">", headingRank, headingStyle);
var after = string.format("</{0}>", headingRank);
@Html.Sitecore().Field(Templates.PageText.Fields.PageTextHeading.ToString(), Model.Item, new { Before = before, After = after })
```

Comment: Which explains why it worked for my link ... Thanks!